# How to inject moq object of Azure docuement Client Assembly in to business logic?

Tags: unit-testing, azure, moq

BusinessLogic project   -> having is using to Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client

In my unit test i have created a mock of

```
        var documentClient = new Mock<IDocumentClient>();

        documentClient.Setup(x => x.ReadDatabaseAsync(It.IsAny<Uri>(), null)).Throws(CreateDocumentClientExceptionForTesting(new Error(), HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
```

now i have to inject documentClient in to BusinessLogic from unit test projects, any ideas on how this has to done ?

Comment: show more code. Help us to help you. what is the target business object, how is the dependency being used?

Comment: there is no dependency injection in both the projects, they are just using Azure Document Client nuget package

Comment: Then the code is too tightly coupled to implementation details. there needs to be the ability to inject the mocked abstractions for the test. Again show the business code where the client is being used so that a solution can be shown on how to refactor the code to make it testable